# Align two divs up and down in footer

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

Though question is trivial and asked multiple time, but my difficulty arises from using Bootstrap 4 may be or some conflicts.

> I want two divs up and down, fixed to bottom. Centered align with text
>   centered align too.

here is code:

```
            <div class="row ">
                <div class="myfooter text-center" style="display: inline-table;">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 ">
                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                            <span class='label label-default'>Copyright &copy; 2018 Some Institute of Sciences, City, Country</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                            <span class='label label-default'>Developed By: Our Technologies (Pvt.) Ltd.</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

And style is:

```
.myfooter {
        position: fixed;
        height: 30px;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #21262929;
    }
```

**Issues:** 
If I change `style="display: inline-table;"` to anything else like `block` one of the div vanishes.

As I am not a designer so please give something ready to use. Thanks

Note: Bootstrap footer class is causing some issue, I can't trace.

Comment: up and down ? you mean two rows ?

Comment: Basically, If you look in html it is just two lines . Copyright and developed by. So how so be arranged in two rows would be ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do this:

```css
.myfooter {
  background-color: #21262929;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="myfooter container-fluid position-fixed fixed-bottom">
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-12">
      <span class='label label-default'>Copyright &copy; 2018 Some Institute of Sciences, City, Country</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
      <span class='label label-default'>Developed By: Our Technologies (Pvt.) Ltd.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And by best advice is to read more about how [boostrap works](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/) and also check the [utilities classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities) that will avoid you adding your own style.